# jQuery: Check for existence of BR as first or last element, including text nodes within a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to test in jQuery for the existence of a `<br />` as the very first, or very last element (including text nodes) within a paragraph. The 2 examples below would be true:

```
<p>
    <br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adiscipling elit.
</p>
```

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adiscipling elit.
    <br />
</p>
```

While this example would be false:

```
<!-- This is false -->
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adiscipling elit
    <br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adiscipling elit.
</p>
```

If true, the following `class`’s of `diog-fail brbr` are to be applied to the containing paragraph element.

Comment: Does it have to be text nodes, or can you change the markup so the text is in, say, a `<span>`? It's typically much easier to ignore text nodes.

Comment: Yes, it has to be text nodes. This is a diagnostic test to check for correct usage of line breaks within an HTML document.

Comment: ...also, unless you remove the white space in your "true" examples, those do actually have text nodes (the white space) as first/last elements, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy using universally supported DOM properties. jQuery isn't much use here.

```
function isBr(el) {
    return el && el.nodeType == 1 && el.tagName == "BR";
}

function isWhitespaceNode(node) {
    return node.nodeType == 3 && /^\s*$/.test(node.data);
}

function isFirstOrLastChildBr(el) {
    var first = el.firstChild;
    if (isWhitespaceNode(first)) first = first.nextSibling;
    if (isBr(first)) return true;

    var last = el.lastChild;
    if (isWhitespaceNode(last)) last = last.previousSibling;
    if (isBr(last)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

So if your `<p>` element had id "foo":

```
var $foo = $("#foo");
if ( isFirstOrLastChildBr($foo[0]) ) {
    $foo.addClass("diog-fail brbr");
}
```

**UPDATE WITH EXAMPLE FOR MULTIPLE ELEMENTS**

To apply this to a set of matched elements:

```
// All paragraphs
$("p").filter(function() {
    return isFirstOrLastChildBr(this);
}).addClass("diog-fail brbr");
```

Comment: Nice one Tim. I would be looking to apply this across all paragraph tags on a site. The idea being to test one of the WCAG 2.0 pain points to make sure paragraphs are formed correctly. Do you think you could supply an example that would apply to all rather than to just #foo?

Comment: And, is this the same Tim Down I worked with at MarketingNet?

Comment: Hi Kev. Yep, the very same Tim Down :) Hope all is well. I've updated my answer, btw.

Comment: Thanks Tim, much appreciated. All well here buddy.

Comment: nice use of DOM +1 much better than using jquery and RegEx

Answer (score 2):

Here is the jsfiddle:

[Using RegEx and If Else condition](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/yUu6q/4/)

```
    $('p').each(function() {
        var temp = this.innerHTML.replace(/^\s*|\s(?=\s)|\s*$/g, "").toLowerCase();
        if (temp.substring(0, 5) == '<br/>' || temp.substring(0, 4) == '<br>' || temp.substring(0, 6) == '<br />') {
            $(this).addClass('diog-fail brbr');
            console.log('start: true');
        } else if (temp.substring(temp.length - 5, temp.length) == '<br/>' || temp.substring(temp.length - 4, temp.length) == '<br>' || temp.substring(temp.length - 6, temp.length) == '<br />') {
            $(this).addClass('diog-fail brbr');
            console.log('end: true');
        } else {
            console.log('none: ' + false);
        }
    });
```

First get all paragraphs and then use RegEx on the innerHTML and flatted it by removing whitespace, newline and etc.  Then do if else condition to see if first and last few substrings matches `<br>, <br/> or <br />`

Comment: Thanks kjy112, I like how you have thought about the different substrings and have used if and else if to separate the conditions of at the start or end of the paragraph. This has allowed me to do a lot more than I initially thought of. Great work.

Comment: Parsing the serialized HTML contents of the `<p>` element using regular expressions is a bad way of doing this. Using DOM methods will be more reliable, easier to understand and more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

As per the test cases you have provided, this will work:

```
$('p').each(function ()
{
    var $this = $(this),
        $brs = $this.children('br'),
        numBRs = $brs.length,
        firstBR = $brs.get(0),
        firstBRprev = firstBR ? firstBR.previousSibling : null,
        firstBRnext = (firstBR && numBRs == 1) ? firstBR.nextSibling : null,
        lastBR = numBRs > 1 ? $brs.get(numBRs) : null,
        lastBRnext = lastBR ? lastBR.nextSibling : null;

    if ((firstBRprev && !firstBRprev.nodeValue.trim()) ||
        (firstBRnext && !firstBRnext.nodeValue.trim()) ||
        (lastBRnext && !lastBRnext.nodeValue.trim()))
    {
        console.log(this);
        $this.addClass('diog-fail brbr');
    }
});
```

Not much jQuery because jQuery hides lots of the nasty DOM business from you, including text nodes.

[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/cjvSU/1/)

Comment: Nice work Matt, this works. However, I have decided to opt for kjy112’s solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function brIsFirstOrLast(selector) {
    var contents = $(selector).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType !== 3 || $.trim($(this).text().replace("\n", "")) !== "";
    });

    var last = contents.last()[0];
    var first = contents.first()[0];

    return (!!last.tagName && last.tagName.toLowerCase() === "br") ||
        (!!first.tagName && first.tagName.toLowerCase() === "br");
}
```

Usage:

```
brIsFirstOrLast("p:first");
```

Note that this function expects the selector to return one result.  You could probably add some more validation too, but this should get you started.

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/F2dwm/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a little bit of RegExp:

```
//returns true if there is a <br/>   at begin or end, otherwise false 
$.trim($('p').html()).match(/(^<br\s*\/?>|<br\s*\/?>$)/i)
```

Otherwise you will have to struggle with browser-dependencies on handling whitespaces as textNodes

Comment: I would not recommend this method. Try it on his input, you'll see - there are actually text nodes in his first two examples, they're just white space.

Comment: I guess that's exactly what he want's to have. I don't think that he realized that depending on the browser all 3 examples will be false(because there are always textNodes at the begin and the end in non-IE-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's one (only *slightly* clunky) way to do it, given the following html for demo purposes:

#### html

```
<div class="testThis">
    <p>Some text, or other with a 'br' at the end.<br /></p>
</div>

<div class="testThis">
    <p><br />Some more text, with a 'br' at the beginning.</p>
</div>

<div class="testThis">
    <p>Some text with a 'br' <br /> in the middle</p>
</div>
```

#### css

```
.testThis {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 1em;
}

.brFirst {
    border-color: #f00;
}

.brLast {
    border-color: #00f;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$('.testThis').each(
    function(){
        var haystack = $(this).find('p').html();
        var needle = '<br>';

        //alert(haystack.indexOf('<br>'));
        if (haystack.indexOf(needle) == 0) {
            $(this).addClass('brFirst');
        }
        else if (haystack.indexOf(needle) == (haystack.length - needle.length)) {
            $(this).addClass('brLast');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AR4D9/1/).

---

**Edited** to update the jQuery, to use the [`trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/trim/) method (so whitespace at the beginning, and end, of the variable `haystack` will be removed):

```
$('.testThis').each(
    function(){
        var haystack = $(this).find('p').html().trim();
        var needle = '<br>'; // Tested in Chrome the `<br />` element is converted to `<br>`

        if (haystack.indexOf(needle) == 0) {
            $(this).addClass('brFirst');
        }
        else if (haystack.indexOf(needle) == (haystack.length - needle.length)) {
            $(this).addClass('brLast');
        }
    });
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AR4D9/2/).

Answer (score 0):

For removing `<br>` from inside `<p>` in embedded editor, I use:

```
target.find('p').find('br').each(function () {
    if(! $(this)[0].nextSibling || ! $(this)[0].previousSibling) $(this).remove();
    });
```

For test and change `<p>` class:

```
target.find('p').each(function () {
    let ancestor = $(this);
    $(this).find('br').each(function () {
        console.log(! $(this)[0].nextSibling || ! $(this)[0].previousSibling ? 'edge' : '!edge');
        ancestor.addClass('zorglubissime');
    });
});
```

I hope this helps...

Ooops. This better:

```
target.find('p').each(function () {
    let ancestor = $(this);
    $(this).find('br').each(function () {
        if(! $(this)[0].nextSibling || ! $(this)[0].previousSibling)
            ancestor.addClass('zorglubissime');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors

So `$('p > br:first-child, p > br:last-child').length > 0`

Comment: I'm not sure that those pseudo-classes include text nodes. **Edit** nope, that won't work. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/cjvSU/

Comment: Thanks Yads, but is some of your code missing? I have not seen a selector which then goes in to <code>.length > 0</code>. Also this is not then adding the required classes to the paragraph.

Comment: @Matt Ball — I’m not sure that they do either, but with my limited knowledge of jQuery, I was wondering if the `.length` would handle this some how. Yads?

Comment: @DigiKev: see my comment edit (the jsfiddle). Also, don't use `<code>` tags in comments, use backticks: `\``.

Comment: @Matt Ball — that doesn’t answer my question, it just proves that Yads answer does not work in this situation. I would prefer to know the answer.